# Iteratively sorting and inplace replacing files using bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have several gene expression files that were sorted incorrectly by gene name. I could just go through the list manually and sort each one using sort, but I'd like to automate the process in case I need to do it again (plus it'll save me time now). The main issue I have is somehow setting the results of using find to select the correct files to a list I can iterate over.

I know I can sort the files by gene name using this code:

```
sort -d -k1 -o fileName fileName
```

But, I'm not well-versed in using loops in bash.

Basically I'd like to perform this operation:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.tpm -o -iname \*.cnt \)
# somehow set the results of find to list I can iterate over
for fileName in fileList
do
sort -d -k1 -o fileName fileName
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fileList=$(find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.tpm -o -iname \*.cnt \))
for fileName in fileList
do
    sort -d -k1 -o fileName fileName
done
```

If your filename contains spaces, before doing this loop, set `IFS=$'\n'`, so that newline is used as separator instead. There might be a more safe method of doing this. I mentioned the best I knew.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-exec` feature of `find`:

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.tpm -o -iname \*.cnt \) -exec sort -d -k1 -o {} {} \;
```

`{}` will be expanded to filenames in the `exec` part, and `find` will take care of the iteration over all files found.

Comment: I figured using exec might be a good substitute to using a loop. Thank you!

Comment: Not all `find` implementations support multiple `{}`s in a single `-exec` phrase, POSIX spec says it's unspecified behaviour. Consider adding a note that this solution will not work with all `find`s or implement inplace editing with temp files and shell features.